# Print a substring of an array value

Tags: perl

I have an array in the third element `dataArr[2]`, I know it contains a 10 digit phone.  I need to only read or print the first 6 digits. For instance if my phone is `8329001111`, I need to print out the `832900`.  I tried to see if I can use `substr` but I keep reading or printing the full list. Do I need to dereference..

Comment: show what you tried using substr

Comment: You're going to have to show the code for us to know what is wrong. `substr` does work, if used correctly.

Comment: There is not enough information to usefully answer your question. It should be put on hold until such a time as it is updated with the relevant information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
$dataArr[2] =~ s/\s//g; # ensure there's no spaces

print substr($dataArr[2], 0, 6);
#               ^         ^  ^
#            variable     |  |
#             offset start|
#                            |
#                          substring length
```